# magento jquery toggle not working in home page but working in product page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento, styles

I have created a jquery simple toggle dropdown menu. I placed it in my toplinks to display as a simple menu for selling. When I clik this, It is not showing the div.
Once When I clicked the Item from the product page. It worked fine.
I am guessing about Jquery conflicts and I have tried as much as possible!

Thank you for your answers in advance

Comment: Please post example code.

Comment: checkout the script errors in console panel of your browser

Answer (score 0):

Open up your Chromium-Browser and your console

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#opening_the_console

Type `jQuery` into the console and press enter

If you get: `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` then you have not included jQuery

Post any errors you get in your console after refreshing the page...